# Sharepoint site Excel file operations using Java graph apis

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Would like to **create the excel file on sharepoint site** using Java Graph API , also would like to **get the id of the same file** so that modifications on the file can be done using the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

1. One should have the Drive Id , Site Id handy for doing this.
2. Create a folder on your sharepoint site , share the same folder in one drive so that the paths can be used to upload the excel file.
3. Use the below given link for more information.
   https://rahul-metangale.medium.com/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-using-azure-graph-api-9deacce57449
4. There is more to this than specified in this blog.